# AWS Amplify: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: google-chrome, react-router, create-react-app, aws-amplify

I am getting several warnings when loading my website on Google Chrome similar to the following:

```
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not parse content for https://mywebsite.com/static/js/2.abcd1234.chunk.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

My webapp is a React application (create-react-app) deployed on AWS Amplify. I do not get these warnings when running the app locally. How do I get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem caused by using `react-router` with AWS amplify. See [this github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1326#issuecomment-485923845). It suggests adding the following entry in the `Rewrites and redirects` section of App settings in AWS Amplify:

```
Source address:
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf)$)([^.]+$)/>

Target address:
/index.html

Type:
200 (Rewrite)
```

To solve my problem, I added the `map` extension to this regex:

Source address:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked my *Rewrites and redirects* settings and it was already configured as per the below answer by "roob" but also had `json` at the end. I removed it to see if that helped. Either way, I still got the error.

More research with a colleague and found another root cause. Answered here:
[AWS Amplify error: Failed to parse source map... file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72019210/aws-amplify-error-failed-to-parse-source-map-file-error-enoent-no-such-fi)