# AWS Amplify error: Failed to parse source map... file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, sweetalert

Using Amplify to deploy my React app (created with `create-react-app`) and I get the following error.

```
2022-04-26T18:52:09.555Z [INFO]: Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Buttons.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Buttons.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Content.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Content.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/CustomIcon.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/CustomIcon.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/ErrorIcon.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/ErrorIcon.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/InfoIcon.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/InfoIcon.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Input.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Input.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Overlay.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Overlay.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/SuccessIcon.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/SuccessIcon.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/SweetAlert.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/SweetAlert.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Title.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/Title.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/ValidationMessage.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/ValidationMessage.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/WarningIcon.tsx' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/components/WarningIcon.tsx'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/constants/patterns.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/constants/patterns.ts'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/default-props.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/default-props.ts'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/index.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/index.ts'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/prop-types.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/prop-types.ts'
                                 Failed to parse source map from '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/styles/SweetAlertStyles.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src963792318/src/pn-toolbox-react/node_modules/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/src/styles/SweetAlertStyles.ts'
```

I checked the solution provided here
[AWS Amplify: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61824173/aws-amplify-devtools-failed-to-load-sourcemap-unexpected-token-in-json-at-po)
but that is already configured as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague's assistance, this resolved this issue.

Add `"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` to the `"build"` line:

**Before**

`"build": "react-scripts build",`

**After**

`"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",`